# Creating Custom Image popup in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-10

I need to create my custom Image Popup in "Point Of Sale" Odoo module. Here's how i coded in /static/src/xml/image_view_xml path of my module. And here's my code. Please, let me know how to define popup for my module!

```
<t t-name="ProductImagePopupWidget">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="popup popup-image">
            <!--Image Popup Code Here-->
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="button ok">
                    Done
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

Comment: did you show the popup with button and you just to add the image or you want the the code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
I needed the image on the popup of the product I clicked, so here's what I did.

```
<!--Image Popup Code Here-->
<span id="image_view">
    <img t-att-src="widget.image_url"/>
</span>
```